# How to receive multiple arguments in Electron.net

Tags: javascript, c#, electron, electron.net

I want to receive an ipcRenderer.send message with multiple arguments.  The JavaScript looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("btn-submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                ipcRenderer.send("btn-submit", [document.getElementById("uid").nodeValue, document.getElementById("pw").nodeValue]);
            });
```

When I try to create the listening function, located within the controller, I receive a syntax error when I reference args as an array, as shown here:

```
Electron.IpcMain.On("btn-submit", async (args) =>
                {
                    MessageBoxOptions options = new MessageBoxOptions(String.Format("UID: {0} PW:{1}",args[0],args[1]))
                    {
                        Type = MessageBoxType.info,
                        Title = "Information",
                        Buttons = new string[] { "Yes", "No" }
                    };

                    var result = await Electron.Dialog.ShowMessageBoxAsync(options);
                });
```

How do I receive the multiple arguments passed from the ipcRenderer.send method in the ipcMain listening method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `.On(...)` takes an `Action<object>`, when there are multiple arguments you can cast the `object` to `List<object>`, that would fix your syntax issue:

```
Electron.IpcMain.On("btn-submit", async (args) =>
                {
                    var listArgs = (List<object>)args;
                    MessageBoxOptions options = new MessageBoxOptions(String.Format("UID: {0} PW:{1}",listArgs[0],listArgs[1]))
                    {
                        Type = MessageBoxType.info,
                        Title = "Information",
                        Buttons = new string[] { "Yes", "No" }
                    };

                    var result = await Electron.Dialog.ShowMessageBoxAsync(options);
                });
```